# search for multiple columns in a single table sql

Tags: sql

I am using SQL Server 2017. How can I search for multiple column names in a single table?

I can search for a single column name (USERID) in my database with:

```
select * 
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
where COLUMN_NAME like '%USERID%' 
order by TABLE_NAME
```

But, I want to search for all tables that have both USERID and DOB.

Using:

```
select * 
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
where COLUMN_NAME like '%USERID%' OR  COLUMN_NAME like '%DOB%'
order by TABLE_NAME
```

returns a list of all tables that contain the column USERID as well as all tables that contain DOB.

Changing to `AND` results in a completely empty list, which is correct, as a single column would not contain both terms

Comment: "Does not work for me" tells us nothing. Why does it not work? Does it throw an error? Does it return more or less than you were expecting? Be descriptive and show sample output

Comment: @dfundako updated question to describe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try below -

```
select TABLE_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
where COLUMN_NAME like '%USERID%' OR  COLUMN_NAME like '%DOB%'
group by TABLE_NAME
having count(distinct COLUMN_NAME)=2
```

Comment: Be careful with that though. DOB is a common enough substring. And that logic doesn't require a match on *both* conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Below query will give you desired results:

```
;WITH cte
 AS (SELECT object_id , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY object_id
     ORDER BY object_id) AS rn
     FROM sys.columns AS c
     WHERE c.name = 'USERID'
           OR 
           c.name = 'DOB')
 SELECT s.name + '.' + t.name
 FROM sys.tables AS t INNER JOIN cte AS c ON t.object_id = c.object_id
                      INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
 WHERE c.rn > 1;
```

Please note to use exact column names with = operator and not like operator to get the correct results.